# How do I set the caption of a window in VBA using SetWindowText and its handle?

Tags: vba

I am using VBA from 32-bit Excel 365, on Windows 10.

Assuming that I have the handle of a notepad window in `hWndApp`, why does the following not set the caption of the window? Rather, it appears to do nothing.

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" _
   Alias "SetWindowTextA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal _
   lpString As String) As Long

Call SetWindowText(hWndApp, "The handle to notepad is " & CStr(hWndApp))
```

Comment: It should work. I am afraid that your code uses a wrong Notepad window handle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, **close all Notepad sessions**, open a **new empty Notepad window** and run the next code. Check in Task manager if any hidden such a process exists and kill it, if any:

```
Sub testChangeNotepadTitle()
   Dim hWndApp As Long
    hWndApp = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Untitled - Notepad"): Debug.Print hWndApp
    SetWindowText hWndApp, "The handle to notepad is " & CStr(hWndApp)
End Sub
```

Doesn't it work? If it works, this only mean that the window handle you use is wrong...

You maybe have more Notepad windows open and API find the first one, not the one you think it is...

Comment: Thanks. You were spot on. I didn't think to check the function that returned the handle. Just for completeness, here is the code for FindWindow `Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As Any, ByVal lpWindowName As Any) As Long`

Comment: @gordon613 I thought you have the API. Otherwise, how talking about a window handle...? Apropos, how did your previous code try obtaining the Notepad window handle?

Comment: Understood. I was testing some code from http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/system/shellhwnd.htm. The hwnd was returned using the StartShell function. I wanted to post the minimum code possible... I didn't realize the problem was somewhere else....

Comment: @gordon613 Why simple, when complicated is possible... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru Solid logic +:) Posted a late complete example of conditional compiling with the main intention to demonstrate the `PtrSafe` syntax under `VBA7` below.

Answer (score 3):

As late addition to the accepted answer an example of conditional compilation meeting both the requirements of **MS Office 2010+** (keyword `VBA7`) and of other/elder versions (e.g. Office 2007).

The API functions under `VBA7` officially *do* demand `LongPtr` types for for pointers to a → **handle** or → *memory location* (note the special `PtrSafe` prefix!).

So a **window handle** is declared as `LongPtr` in Office 2010 or higher and as `Long` in versions before; consequently it is necessary to differentiate between the different versions by conditional compile constants (#If VBA7 Then .. #End If). -
*Note:* Combining these possibilities may also require differentiated variable declarations in user procedures (c.f. `testChangeNotepadTitle`)

*Hint:* `LongPtr` is not a true data type because it transforms to the right datatype depending on the actual 32/64-bit environment.

Note that 64-bit systems can be installed either as 32-bit office or 64 bit office. LongPtr enables writing portable code that can run in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments.

*Side note:* The `#If Win64` directive in addition to `VBA7` is rarely needed in some special situations (e.g. loading two different dlls or use functions with different signatures on 32 bit and 64 bit systems).

**API functions**

```
Option Explicit         ' declaration head of code module

#If VBA7 Then           ' MS Office 2010+
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowTextA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpString As String) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
    Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowTextA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpString As String) As Long
#End If
```

**Calling procedure `testChangeNotepadTitle`**

```
Sub testChangeNotepadTitle()
   Const NotePadTitle As String = "Untitled - Notepad"   ' EN-US
  'Const NotePadTitle As String = "Unbenannt - Editor"   ' DE
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim hwndapp As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hwndapp As Long
    #End If
    hwndapp = FindWindow(vbNullString, NotePadTitle): Debug.Print hwndapp
    SetWindowText hwndapp, "The handle to notepad is " & CStr(hwndapp)
End Sub
```

*Side note*  The window title *"Untitled - Notepad"* follows regional settings; so I added an example for e.g. Germany/Austria (DE) - titled *"Unbenannt - Editor"* - as outcommented procedure constant.

Comment: Yes, this is the logic. I only tried to show a working piece of code. It is also good to be known that you may find a Notepad window where a specific file is open. I used it in a CorelDRAW application like alternative to barcode scan. Then, the code is able to read the last row of the respective text last line in the editor. I used `TxtHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Corel_Scan.txt - Notepad")`, followed by `If TxtHwnd = 0 Then TxtHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Corel_Scan - Notepad")`, for computers set to not show extensions for known files...